# How to get the second string of the input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char command[256];
    char *token;
    const char s[2] = " ";

    fprintf(stdout, "$ Please enter a command \n");
    fflush( stdout );

    fgets ( command, 256, stdin );
    token = strtok(command, s);

    if (strcmp(token, "loaddungeon") == 0){
        fprintf(stdout, "$ loaded successfully \n");
        fflush( stdout );
    }
}
```

I am trying to use strtok to get the second string of the input. For instance, if the input is  "`loaddungeon dfile.txt`", what I want to get is the "`dfile.txt`". My function is able to get the string "`loaddungeon`". But I have no idea how to get the second string "`dfile.txt`". Can anyone tell me how to do it?

(Consider the input is always "`loaddungeon dfile.txt`".)

Comment: User's input may be `"dfile.txt\n"`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the second string, you need to pass `NULL` to `strtok()`. Keep in mind that `fgets()` retains the newline character from the input line, so you should change your delimiter definition from `char s[2] = " ";` to `char s[] = " \r\n";`, or `char s* = " \r\n"`. This way the second token will not include any newline characters. Also note that `strtok()` returns a `NULL` pointer if no token is found, so the below code tests for this before printing the read tokens.

But, since you say that there are only two strings, I would consider just using `sscanf()` for this. Using the `%s` conversion specifier, `sscanf()` will read characters into a string until a whitespace character is encountered, but will not include this whitespace character in the string. When you use the `%s` specifier in a `scanf()` type function, you should specify a maximum field width to avoid buffer overflow. This maximum width should be one less than the size of the buffer to leave room for the `'\0'` string terminator, **255** in this case. The `sscanf()` function returns the number of successful assignments made, which should be **2** in this case. The `sscanf()` approach shown below (commented out) checks this return value before printing the strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_MAX  256

int main(void) {

    char command[BUFFER_MAX];
    char *token1 = NULL;
    char *token2 = NULL;
    const char *s = " \r\n";

    fprintf(stdout, "$ Please enter a command \n");
    fflush( stdout );

    fgets ( command, BUFFER_MAX, stdin );

    token1 = strtok(command, s);
    token2 = strtok(NULL, s);

    if (token1 && token2 && strcmp(token1, "loaddungeon") == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "$ loaded successfully: %s\n", token2);
        fflush( stdout );
    }

    /* or instead do this */
/*
    char word1[BUFFER_MAX], word2[BUFFER_MAX];
    if (sscanf(command, "%255s %255s", word1, word2) == 2) {
        if (strcmp(word1, "loaddungeon") == 0){
            fprintf(stdout, "$ loaded successfully: %s\n", word2);
            fflush( stdout );
        }
    }
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every call to `strtok` will return a pointer to the last token found in the given string (or null if there is none left). To retrieve the second token with space as a delimiter, you need to call `strtok` for the second time.

```
int main()
{
    char command[256];
    char *token1 = NULL;
    char *token2 = NULL;
    const char s[2] = " ";
    fprintf(stdout, "$ Please enter a command \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(command, 256, stdin);
    token1 = strtok(command, s); // now points to first word
    if (NULL != token1) {
        token2 = strtok(NULL, s); // now points to second word
    }
    if (NULL != token2) {
        if (strcmp(token2, "loaddungeon") == 0){
           fprintf(stdout, "$ loaded successfully \n");
           fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to have two 'token pointers' — maybe `char *operation; char *operand;` — and then use `operation = strtok(command, " \n"); operand = strtok(NULL, " \n");`. I omitted the test; it isn't bad, but it isn't critical. If you continue invoking `strtok(NULL, "…")`, it continues returning null. (Standard says: _The `strtok` function then searches from there for a character that is contained in the current separator string. If no such character is found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer._

Comment: That is a totally valid point. Subsequent calls should almost always happen in a loop. OP however suggested he/she expects two tokens to be present and he/she is seeking only the second one.

Comment: Well, the code compares the first token with `loaddungeon` and then wants to be able to use the second token for the file to be loaded as the dungeon.  So I think both are needed.  Note that the other answer is using `token1` and `token2` where I'm hypothesizing `operator` and `operand` might be appropriate — but the choice of name is 100% up to you and as long as they're different, it should work.  (So, by all means use `z` and `fancy_pants_extra_long_name` — but I'd think you're nearly as weird as me.)

Comment: My bad. You are right. Sorry I did not pay attention. I just edited my answer.