# cannot read the string generated by the strtok function

Tags: c

```
 #Function1       
    char command[256];
    char *token;
    char *token2;
        const char s[2] = " ";

    fprintf(stdout, "$ Please enter a command \n");
    fflush( stdout );
    fgets ( command, 256, stdin );
    token = strtok(command, s);
    token2 = strtok(NULL, s);

    if ((fp= fopen(token2, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file");
        exit(1);}

#Function 2

    char command[256];
    char *token;
    char *token2;
        const char s[2] = " ";

    fprintf(stdout, "$ Please enter a command \n");
    fflush( stdout );
    fgets ( command, 256, stdin );
    token = strtok(command, s);
    token2 = strtok(NULL, s);

    if ((fp= fopen("dfile.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file");
        exit(1);}
```

These two functions take a string(in the case, the string is always "loaddungeon dfile.txt") These two functions are pretty much the same except for one tiny difference. In the second function, I changed the token2 to "dfile.txt".

The first function prints out "cannot open file"

while the second function successfully reads the file.

but I tried to print the token2 in the first function as followed

```
printf("%s\n", token2);
```

it prints "dfile.txt".

How could this happen? Why the first function cannot read the token2 which is exactly the same as "dfile.txt". Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I [cannot reproduce your issue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d856f7ebf806adc)

Comment: Did you try to copy my code entirely?

Comment: A point for future visits on SO. If you mean to ask *"Did you try to copy my code entirely?"* then your code should be a [mcve].

Comment: You might [look at this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710458/how-to-get-the-second-string-of-the-input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's propably because of the newline at the end of token2 (the debugger showed it); When reading in a line through `fgets`, the string read in it often contains a new line character `'\n'` at the end. This character may, though not obvious in the console, influence some other functions (e.g. `fopen`, which might not find the file then). Hence, remove the trailing new line (as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2693826/2630032)):

```
token2 = strtok(NULL, s);

char *eol;
if (token2 && (eol=strchr(token2,'\n')))
    *eol = 0x0;

if ((fp= fopen(token2, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("cannot open file");
    exit(1);}
```